# Javascript: How to compare both strings in an array to this statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code looks like this right now:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(config.prefix[0]) !== 0) return;
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix[0].length).trim().split(/+/g);
```

and my config.json looks like this:

```
{
    "prefix": ["mikuru", "miku"]
}
```

how can I allow `message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(config.prefix[0]) !== 0` or `message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(config.prefix[1]) !== 0` depending on what `message.content.toLowerCase()` is?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check any `prefix` string exist in `message.content`, you should compare result of `indexOf` with -1 not 0.

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

[(MDN) String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

I not really understand your question. What do you really want? Can you show the expected result ?

Comment: The expected result would be the program would not return, and args variable would slice out the config.prefix. regardless of whether the message began with the first prefix in the array or the second

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) here.

In your case, you can use it like this:

`[“mikuru”,“miku”].includes(message.content.toLowerCase())`

Or even better:

`prefix.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())`

Hope this helps.